# How to overwrite a PHP session variable

Tags: php, session, overwrite

Is this possible?

```
if ($_SESSION['variable'] = 'one' {
    $_SESSION['variable'] = 'car';
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working. 
Is this enough information?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Make sure variable is one though and remember to use session_start(); at the beginning of the file. Also, its: "if ($_SESSION['variable'] == 'one'){}"

Comment: `==` in the if statement and closing `)` as well

Comment: and remember to close bracket for if ) :D

Comment: I didn't put the syntax in correctly here, I don't think it's the problem,
this is my code
`if ($_SESSION['variable'] == 'one') {

 $_SESSION['variable'] = 'car'; 

 }`
this should work, right? 
And I am using `session_start();`

Comment: @user2118228 you tell us... Did it work?

Comment: no! i'll look into it more! unless someone knows a stipulation which would prevent it from being over-written...

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can overwrite variables, but your codes syntax is wrong, try:

```
if ($_SESSION['variable'] == 'one') {
    $_SESSION['variable'] = 'car';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax error and also in `if` clause your are not checking you are assigning the value

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['variable'] == 'one') {
$_SESSION['variable'] = 'car';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is due to your syntax errors.

Here's an example that might help you understand what's going on...

```
$_SESSION['variable'] = 'one';
// use == for comparison... = for variable assignment
if($_SESSION['variable'] == 'one'){
    // reassign
    $_SESSION['variable'] = 'car';
}

var_dump($_SESSION);

// array(1) { ["variable"]=> string(3) "car" }
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vyFX62)**

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error or probably a typo in your code
Try this

```
if ($_SESSION['variable'] == 'one') {
    $_SESSION['variable'] = 'car';
}
```